Why doesn't my Declarative Net Request work on google search?
I'm trying to redirect any request to Google to another site. What I currently have works for google.com and google.com/test (they go to example.com and example.com/test respectively), but not for a Google search (google.com/search?...). What am I doing wrong here?
My manifest:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Redirect Google",
    "version": "1.0",
    "declarative_net_request": {
        "rule_resources": [{
            "id": "ruleset_1",
            "enabled": true,
            "path": "rules_1.json"
        }]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "declarativeNetRequest"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*.google.com/*"
    ]
}

My rules_1.json:
[{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": { 
        "type": "redirect",
        "redirect": {
            "transform": {
                "host": "example.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "condition": {
        "urlFilter": "||google.com",
        "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
}]

Edit: As woxxom rightly noted in the comments: I'm using Opera GX. I did already enable the "Allow access to the search page results" checkbox for my extension.

You're using Opera browser which denies access to search engine by default. You can enable it manually in chrome://extensions, AFAIK.

@woxxom You're right that I use Opera. But I did enable the "Allow access to the search page results" checkbox in the extension settings. I'll edit that info into the post, thanks.

I guess you need to reload the extension, otherwise it's a bug in the browser.

I'm constantly reloading the extension when I make a change, but I guess I could try to completely remove it and add it again.
